# Searching for remote job offer for psychologies expertise

Tags: test

I am curious about finding some site or forum for **remote job offer** or **volunteer job opportunities** for people with a **Master in Psychology** From ***middle east countries***  (For example **Iran** country).

I have searched for **[psychology remote job offer](https://www.google.com/search?q=%20psychology%20remote%20job%20offer&sxsrf=ALeKk031LU_2XAhDioqslZZ2Vw8Znt4B0w%3A1622993389113&ei=7em8YNKvBoK0swW30b-IAw&oq=%20psychology%20remote%20job%20offer&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANQxVpYxVpg9FtoAHABeACAAcIDiAHCA5IBAzQtMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiS2rjDqYPxAhUC2qwKHbfoDzEQ4dUDCA4&uact=5)** and I found some results like the [below post](https://www.flexjobs.com/blog/post/companies-hiring-virtual-assistant-jobs-v2/):

[image]

But as i am not expert in this filed, I asked here to find out better result.

Thanks.